# Fedora 21 packages repo in cobbler not found

Tags: repository, fedora, provisioning

I am attempting to install Fedora 21 with additional packages (dhcp, tftp-server, tftp, subversion, vim) using cobbler as my provisioning system over pxeboot.

The problem is that the installation will show an error about packages/groups not existing when it tries to install packages for Fedora, specifically it will pop up an error for all of the packages I try to install in the list below. It seems that the repo information is not right because not a single one of my packages is being installed even though when I check the repo on the web they are present.Here are the relevant sections from my kickstart file.

```
install
url --url=http://192.168.1.1/cblr/links/Fedora_21_Server-i386/
repo --name="Fedora_21_i386_Server" --baseurl=http://192.168.1.1/cblr/repo_mirror/Fedora_21_i386/


auth --useshadow --passalgo=md5


graphical
firstboot --disable

keyboard us
lang en_US
timezone America/Los_Angeles

selinux --disabled
logging --level=info
reboot

bootloader --location=mbr
zerombr


clearpart --all --initlabel
part swap --fstype="swap" --size=1000
part / --fstype="ext3" --grow --size=1

%packages

@base
@base-x
@editors
@graphical-internet
@system-tools
@admin-tools
@fonts
@lxde-desktop

dhcp
tftp
tftp-server
subversion
vim-enhanced
vsftpd
minicom
%end
```

I have also tried setting --baseurl as a Fedora mirror (--baseurl=http://mirror.pnl.gov/fedora/linux/releases/21/Server/i386/os/) but that does not work either. I have the above repo added as a cobbler repo and I have linked my Fedora 21 profile to it. One caveat is that I chose "No" for the local mirror option because right now my VM does not have enough space for the Fedora repo.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to install the packages in a post-install section using standard yum commands. For example,

%post
yum -y install minicom
yum -y install vsftpd

I've used this workaround with F20 installs.

Comment: Please use markdown formatting for the commands to improve readability. Here, you should put 4 spaces before each command.